# How to unpack/convert a stringified JSON array to normal JSON array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a Rails 5.2 app.
In this app I am sending parameter from my Angular app to the server with a JSON.stringify object that looks like this when it arrives to the server:

```
"[{\"price\":\"silver\"},{\"price\":\"bronze\"}]"
```

I want to "unpack" it to look like a real JSON object again (because Stripe, that I will send this too only accept a JSON object:

```
[{"price":"silver"},{"price":"bronze"}]
```

If I run JSON.parse it only converts to a Hash which is not what I want.

Comment: The million dollar question is why you're sending garbage in the first place? And you do realize that the equivilent to JSON objects in Ruby is a hash and thats actually an array of objects?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to operate or manipulate that JSON then you need to parse it to Hash.

JSON is treated as a string in ruby and you cannot operate properly on that so by parsing it to hash you can manipulate it using ruby also you can again change the resulting hash back to JSON string and as far as I've worked with Stripe it will work, so

For parsing JSON to Hash:

```
hash = JSON.parse(json_string)
```

For parsing Hash to JSON:

```
json_string = JSON.generate(hash)
```

or

```
json_string = hash.to_json
```